# SQLite querying two rows simultaneously and storing the data in one string

Tags: java, sqlite

Let's say I have a SQLite table like so:

```
public static final String DataBaseName = "test1.db";
    public static final String DataTableName = "jobsTable";
    public static final String ColID = "ID";
    public static final String ColPlace = "placeName";
    public static final String ColPosition = "position";
    public static final String ColStartingTime = "startingTime";
    public static final String ColHours = "hours";
    public static final String ColAddress = "address";
    public static final String ColPhoneNumber = "phoneNumber";
```

I already know how to write a query for one row and store the values inside an ArrayList. Bellow code gets all the members of the placeName colum and stores them in an arraylist. e.g.

```
"placename1","placeName2","placeName3","placeName4",...
```

Code:

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPlacesNames() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select placeName FROM " + DataTableName,null);
        ArrayList<String> companyNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        while(result.moveToNext()) {
            String places = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("placeName"));
            companyNames.add(places);
        }

        return companyNames;
    }
```

I'm trying to write a method like above that gets the values from two columns (`PlaceName` and `position`) and store them like:

```
"placeName1/position1","placeName2/position2","placeName3/position3","placeName4/position4",...
```

How can this be done? Thank you

Comment: but why do you want to do that? Isn't it easier to just directly process the result?

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllCompanyPositionsAndNamesAndPhone() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select placeName, position, startingTime FROM " + DataTableName,null);
        ArrayList<String> companyPositions = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(result.moveToNext()) {
            String position = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("position"));
            String places = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("placeName"));
            String phoneNum = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("startingTime"));
            String merged = places + "/" + position + "\n" + "Starts on: " + phoneNum;
            companyPositions.add(merged);

        }
        return companyPositions;
```

Answer (score 0):

i Suggest to use Hashmap to save a key/value data this is my solution .

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllPlacesNames() {
SQLiteDatabase mydb = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor result = mydb.rawQuery("select placeName, position FROM " + DataTableName,null);

HashMap<String, Integer> data= new HashMap<String, String>();

while(result.moveToNext()) {


map.put(result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("placeName")), result.getString(result.getColumnIndex("position")));

}
```

**H@ppy c0de !!**